# multiple filter rule doesn't apply?

Tags: image, css, css-filters

I'm trying to use multiple filters on a background-image

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0');
  filter: grayscale(50%) blur(3px) brightness(10%);
}
```

it ignores the rule I've put in ...can't even do 1 at a time...can I not use filters on background images?

Answer (score 1):

The filter is working fine but the background image is no more inside the body. Here you are facing a [special background behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds) that propagate the value of background from the body to the canvas AND it's removed from the body. In other words, your background is moved to an upper element and the filter is kept on the body.

To notice this, simply apply a background to the html element and you will disable the propagation effect thus the filter will work as expected:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0');
  filter: grayscale(50%) blur(3px) brightness(10%);
  height:200px; /*you need a height to see the image !*/
}
html {
 background:red;
}
```

By the way, it's not a good solution to apply filter to whole body as it will also affect the content. If you want to filter only the image better consider a pseudo element that will be your background layer and where you can apply the filer without affecting the content:

```css
body {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  height:200px; /*you need a height to see the image !*/
}
body:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0');
  filter: grayscale(50%) blur(3px) brightness(10%);
}
```

Comment: thank you...i did put it the image into a pseudo-class, please see fiddles above...tyvm :)

Comment: @ScatterBrainz you have typo error, please check well the name of the classes, it's case sensitive

Comment: @ScatterBrainz and in some fiddle you are defining classes that you aren't using

Comment: sorry my bad typing -> please see -> https://jsfiddle.net/howdc0mf/1/ and/or https://jsfiddle.net/n593xzgt/3/ and or https://jsfiddle.net/jbnmfpud/1/ does jsfiddle not load url images?

Comment: @ScatterBrainz the image is not loading, check the link. It's working fine with my image : https://jsfiddle.net/n593xzgt/4/

Comment: Thanks for answer, appreciate it, I've come into a question, perhaps you can answer ... when I put the background-image directly in the <body> tag, it shows up in the browser, but when I reference it in the pseudo-class .pageWrapper identical code (width: 100%;, height: 100%;) it disappears? just wondering why?

Comment: please refer to new stack question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028243/multiple-filters-with-text-on-top-absolute-stops-page-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` property on `background-image`

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.module {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: #ff43ea;
  position: relative;
}
.module::before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494645009625-cc17363a5f20?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=bd502af39c922553e5a13624d4f44f40);
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.module-inside {
  position: relative;
  font: bold 42px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="module">
  <div class="module-inside">
    Module
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you both for your answers, but clearly I'm doing something wrong still...my fiddle, I've tried both solutions above - I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, you can check them both out at JsFiddle I have 3 variations, including the code provided here .... https://jsfiddle.net/howdc0mf/ and https://jsfiddle.net/n593xzgt/2/ and https://jsfiddle.net/jbnmfpud/, i still have to be able since the image will end up being dark shades of gray/black -> i still have to put white text ontop of that. which should just be another div with position: absolute...am i right? tyvm :)